# US Citizen with French residency and with a French auto-entrepreneurship. How do I do taxes?

Tags: usa, france, taxes, freelance

Here's my situation: My family moved to France when I was 14 in 2011. I have a French residency card (titre de séjour) which allows me to work. I have a freelance translation business registered under French law (a business I've had since 2016). I moved out of my family home in May 2017, which is why this year will be my first time paying taxes for both countries.

**My question is: how do I go about doing my US taxes? What do I declare and not declare?**

I'm quite lost when it comes to the IRS website. I don't know if I declare what I've made with my business as my business is French, but as my own employer, I'm American. When asking my mother, she said that I wouldn't have to pay income tax, but I would have to pay social contribution tax (Social Security, Medicare, Medicaid, etc.), though she wasn't sure either.

Also, I don't know if this is important, but I live with my partner, who is French. I'm guessing the IRS doesn't care about him, as he isn't American, but the more information the better I guess.

Thank you in advance for your help, as this is all quite confusing.

Comment: The IRS does not care about your partner unless you are legally married.  You must declare all of your income, but if your business is a separate legal entity then your personal income only comprises payments to you from the business.  The tax forms and their instructions, along with the relevant publications, should answer all of your questions, though you may find it worthwhile to hire someone.

Comment: If you are doing this for the first time, my advice is to hire a tax professional. Once you've done it once successfully you might be able to do it yourself the second time.